# How to make an accurate timer on Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

Basically what I just do to create a timer is `float timer += 1 * deltaTime` and it will add 1 every second, but I'm having a problem on using it.

```
if(timer < 2){
    //do something
}
```

I want the if statement to stop running the code when timer is at 2 seconds, buy since I cannot do `if(timer != 2f)` because it will not even detect 2 seconds because it's too fast. This means I have to put a condition `timer < 2f`, which is not accurate and always gives me inacurate results.

Comment: You should almost never compare floats and doubles by equality, they are not meant to be exact numbers. The little bit of code you showed us looks okay to me, can you describe what you mean with "inaccurate results"?

Comment: I'm trying to make a free fall simulator, which the user can input the free fall time, since the timer is inaccurate then the computation sometimes is off by 0.1

Comment: @Todd Sewell I wan't the if statement to stop at exactly 2 seconds

Comment: Something like `if(timer >= 2 - marginOfError) return;` would do the trick. Margin should be fairly small, something like 1/60f. Since you are using libgdx, ill assume that you are drawing some stuff to the screen. You probably do that at 60 fps, so thats your margin of error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a hand made timer why not use a `Task` and a boolean?

Pseudo code below;

```
boolean stop = false;

Timer.schedule(new Task() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stop = true;
    }
}, 2f);
```

Then in your render method;

```
 render() {

     if (!stop) {

         // Freefall
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your code to process for X seconds and no more (where X can be a floating point value such as 12.556 seconds).

I'm going to propose a single-threaded alternative where you have a custom Timer class that manages your freefall logic as shown below. It watches the progress and if it sees something greater than the duration, it "lies" to the internal logic so that your logic is only executed for the amount of time specified (within a configurable margin of error since we're playing with floats).

The example below demonstrates this sort of thing without using libGDX (just in case folks using other libraries are interested), but it would be trivial to swap out my simulated `getDeltaTime()` method with `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`.

```
package tech.otter.timing;

/**
 * Created by john on 11/20/16.
 */
public class TimingExample {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        boolean complete = false;

        Timer t = new Timer(15f) {
            // You could implement your logic here.
            @Override
            void action(float delta) {
                System.out.println(progress);
            }
        };

        while(!complete) {
            complete = t.update(getDeltaTime());
        }

        assert t.progress < t.duration;
        assert t.progress + t.errorMargin > t.duration;
    }

    /**
     * Simulates processing time by returning 0-100ms.
     * @return The number of milliseconds that have allegedly elapsed since the last call.
     */
    public static float getDeltaTime() {
        return (float)(Math.random() / 10);
    }

    abstract static class Timer {
        private float duration;
        protected float progress;
        private float errorMargin;

        public Timer(float duration) {
            this(duration, 0.0001f);
        }
        public Timer(float duration, float errorMargin) {
            this.duration = duration;
            this.errorMargin = errorMargin;
            this.progress = 0f;
        }

        /**
         * Update the timer based on how long since the last call.
         * @param delta The amount of time since the last call.
         * @return Whether the timer's progressed has met the duration.
         */
        public boolean update(float delta) {
            // This if-statement "caps" the delta so that we will never exceed the duration.
            if(progress + delta > duration) {
                delta = duration - progress;
            }
            progress += delta;
            action(delta);

            // Return "true" if the progress is equal to the duration (+/- a small margin just in case since we use floats).
            return progress + errorMargin > duration && progress - errorMargin < duration;
        }

        /**
         * Override this method with your game logic.
         * You should not call it directly.
         * @param delta The amount of time that has elapsed since the timer was last updated.
         */
        abstract void action(float delta);
    }
}
```